# Kotlin float number with 2 decimals to string without precision loss

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android-Kotlin I am getting float number from backend (for example num = 10000000.47)
When I try to String.format it and add that number in my balanceTextview it shows it with exponent (something like 1.0E10).

I want to show number normally without exponent and with 2 decimals. (Without presicion loss!)

Tried to use DecimalFormat("#.##") but it didn't help me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
num = 10000000.47f
 val dec = DecimalFormat("#.##")
 var result = dec.format(num)

my result is: 10000000
It losts my decimal places
```

Comment: Can you show us how you tried it? We really need to see the code in order to help...

Comment: What's `amount`? Shouldn't that be `num`?

Comment: yes, my bad I just corrected it

Answer (score 16):

The issue is your number type. According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html):

> For variables initialized with fractional numbers, the compiler infers the Double type. To explicitly specify the Float type for a value, add the suffix f or F. If such a value contains more than 6-7 decimal digits, it will be rounded.

With an example that shows how information may get lost:

```
val pi = 3.14 // Double
val e = 2.7182818284 // Double
val eFloat = 2.7182818284f // Float, actual value is 2.7182817
```

If the value is specified as `Double` instead of `Float`, i.e.

```
val num = 10000000.47
```

instead of

```
val num = 10000000.47f
```

then your approach works as expected, but could be shortened to:

```
"%.2f".format(num)
```

(note that the shorter version will also print "100" as "100.00" which is different from your approach but potentially still desired behaviour)

If you receive a `Float` from the backend then the information is already lost on your side. Otherwise you should be able to fix the issue by improved parsing.

Comment: I am getting number from backend and it is Float

Comment: Since `print(num)` already shows the loss of decimals I'd argue that you are probably out of luck then.

Comment: You mean I just can't fix this on my side?

Comment: How exactly do you get the number? As JSON number? As JSON string? As...?

Answer (score 0):

The extension function `format` is only available in the JVM. In Kotlin/native, you can use this instead:

```
fun Float.toPrecision(precision: Int) =
    this.toDouble().toPrecision(precision)

fun Double.toPrecision(precision: Int) =
    if (precision < 1) {
        "${this.roundToInt()}"
    } else {
        val p = 10.0.pow(precision)
        val v = (abs(this) * p).roundToInt()
        val i = floor(v / p)
        var f = "${floor(v - (i * p)).toInt()}"
        while (f.length < precision) f = "0$f"
        val s = if (this < 0) "-" else ""
        "$s${i.toInt()}.$f"
    }
```